# How to access the value of an object that doesn't have a Key in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, object, base64

I am trying to load a local image and convert it into Base64 in JavaScript (without loading into browser). When I run the following code:

```
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-to-base64
// installation: npm i -S image-to-base64

const image_path = "1.jpg"   // Path to the image

const imageToBase64 = require('image-to-base64');

const image_base64 = imageToBase64(image_path)
console.log(typeof image_base64)   // object
```

Th Base64 string is saved in "image_base64" variable. The data-type of "image_base64" is Object, but it doesn't have any Key. When I print "image_base64" in console:

```
{'/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4RDcRXhpZgA'}
```

(It is much longer than above.)

I want to have access to the Base64 string inside the Object "image_base64". I tried the following commands:

```
console.log(Object.values(image_base64))   
console.log(image_base64[0])
```

But, they return:

```
[]
undefined
```

If you have any idea how I can get access to the string inside the Object, please let me know.

Comment: Give a try console.log(image_base64)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you are getting is not valid vase64 encoding. You can check this by entering the data into an [online base64 decoder](https://www.base64decode.org/).

The imageToBase64() method is asynchronous and returns a promise which you are not awaiting.

See what kind of output you get from doing this:

```js
imageToBase64(image_path)
    .then(function(image_base64) {
        console.log(image_base64);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

If you're in an ES6 environment, you can `await` the promise:

```js
// async function required for Node < v14
async function convertImage(image_path) {
    try {
        const image_base64 = await imageToBase64(image_path);
        // Do something with image_base64 data
        console.log(image_base64);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. When I use "await", Should I define a async function? Like: async function myFunc() {const image_base64 = await imageToBase64(image_path);}

Comment: Yes, unless you're using Node 14 (which supports top level await), you will need to use an `async function` to use the `await` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked this library and the value you receive from *imageToBase64* function is a promise. To retrieve the value from promise, you can do something like this -

```
let img64 = img64Lib(imgPath);
img64.then(result => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```